# Parsing user input - getting integers from strings and exception handling

Tags: java, gwt

my application will have a text box which the user will edit with numbers (hopefully)

I am using `Integer.parseInt()` to convert the string into a integer, however, there's always the chance the user will not pass in numbers which will throw an exception during `parseInt()`. I am not sure what the convention is for error handling in GWT. Does this work?

```
int number = -1;
try {
  number = Interger.parseInt(inputFromUser);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // error handling like telling user to try again
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just change `Exception` to [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want number-only boxes, use `IntegerBox`, `LongBox`, or `DoubleBox`. They already support rendering and parsing of, respectively, integer, long or double values using locale-aware renderers/parsers (based on `NumberFormat`).

Comment: Yup.do not go for manual codes when framework already providing everything.

Comment: it says there are still experimental, and that I should use them at my own risk

Comment: Only the very first versions of them (pre GWT 2.1, in the `com.google.gwt.app.client` package). They have been moved since the 2.1 release into the now-no-more-experimental `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui` package). Use it without any doubt.